# Azure SSO JWT token is still valid after signing out

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a JWT token which is generated client side and stored in session storage. It is passed to ASP.NET WebApi endpoints that are decorated with the Authorize attribute. If a user signs out of my application then I can delete the token and sign the user out of Azure.

However if the user goes to a different Azure site and signs out then the token that is used in my application remains valid (despite the user being signed out.) How can I force WebApi to call back to Azure and revalidate the token on each request?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: you got the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD JWT access tokens are self signed and the payload contains the *exp* timestamp, datetime until which the token is valid. The relying party application does not communicate with Azure AD to validate the token, instead, it uses the self-signed information.
The only way to *log out*, as you mention, is to delete the token.

When you *log out* from Azure AD SSO you only *log out* of the possibility to create new access tokens, but already issued access tokens will continue to work until they expire.
Try to log out from Azure AD SSO but keep the access token to your application: You will still be able to access it.

So if you want to *log out* from both applications, you will need to delete access tokens for both applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I go to something like microsoftonline in one tab and I go to the azure portal in a second tab. Then I sign out of microsoftonline and press refresh in azure portal I am instantly signed out of Azure portal as well. Do they just set a very short token expiration and keep reissuing tokens?

Comment: They are probably implementing Single Sign Out as described in this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out. An app can check if the AAD session is active by using the techniques there.